# How i can create a layout in android like graph, without using any external library

Tags: android, xml, layout

How I can create a layout in android like graph, without using any external library.

[image]

Comment: what do you want to do with this?

Comment: I just want to draw graphs on it.

Comment: Use pattern as background. Use `Canvas` to draw lines. Use a lot of `1px` views to layout them. Your question is useless without knowing the purpose.

Comment: @MuhammadBilalLiaquat go through https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart For examples https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample

Comment: I am using @Canvas for lines, I just want to put that background on back side my lines programmatically.(but not as an image)

Comment: @MuhammadBilalLiaquat Will you please put your canvas code to get the flow.

Comment: Yes! Check the 3rd Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Canvas for same, here is compltete description for canvas:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

You could create a SurfaceView, in which you can draw to a Canvas in the onDraw() method. To draw your graph, you can use the Path class, and it's moveTo() and lineTo() methods. To change the appearance of the lines, use the Paint class. Then use the Canvases drawPath() method, which takes a Path, and a Paint object. I think it's a bit easier to start with, than OpenGl.

- SurfaceView
- Canvas
- Path
- Paint

[Some Demo](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/drawpath-on-canvas.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomView extends View {
        private Paint paint;
        Context app_context;

        public CustomView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            app_context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            int width = 1000;
            int height = 1200;
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

            paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            paint.setTextSize(50);
            canvas.drawText("Bilal",45f,55f, paint);

            float[] xStopPointsLine1 = new float[]{0f,200.1f,450.5f,650f,850f};
            float[] yStopPointsLine1 = new float[]{100f,380f,540f,400f,720f};
            float[] xStopPointsLine2 = new float[]{20f,170.1f,350.5f,480f,650f};
            float[] yStopPointsLine2 = new float[]{200f,480f,240f,600f,380f};

            for(int i=0; i<yStopPointsLine1.length; i++){
                paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(8);
                if(i==0){
                    canvas.drawLine(xStopPointsLine1[i],yStopPointsLine1[i],xStopPointsLine1[i+1],yStopPointsLine1[i+1], paint);
                    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    canvas.drawLine(xStopPointsLine2[i],yStopPointsLine2[i],xStopPointsLine2[i+1],yStopPointsLine2[i+1], paint);
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    canvas.drawCircle(xStopPointsLine1[i], yStopPointsLine1[i], 12, paint);
                    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    canvas.drawCircle(xStopPointsLine2[i], yStopPointsLine2[i], 12, paint);
                }
                else if(i>0 && i<yStopPointsLine1.length-1)
                {
                    canvas.drawLine(xStopPointsLine1[i],yStopPointsLine1[i],xStopPointsLine1[i+1],yStopPointsLine1[i+1], paint);
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    canvas.drawCircle(xStopPointsLine1[i], yStopPointsLine1[i], 12, paint);
                    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    canvas.drawLine(xStopPointsLine2[i],yStopPointsLine2[i],xStopPointsLine2[i+1],yStopPointsLine2[i+1], paint);
                    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    canvas.drawCircle(xStopPointsLine2[i], yStopPointsLine2[i], 12, paint);
                }
                else if(i == yStopPointsLine1.length-1){
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    canvas.drawCircle(xStopPointsLine1[i], yStopPointsLine1[i], 12, paint);
                    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    canvas.drawCircle(xStopPointsLine2[i], yStopPointsLine2[i], 12, paint);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```